# Is "What 4WD vehicle is necessary for Waipoli Road?" really a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicates, specific-question

Why was [What 4WD vehicle is necessary for Waipoli Road?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/125905/13759) closed as a duplicate of [How much does an SUV help, for driving popular but poorly paved roads on Big Island?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/125554/13759)? The former's about a road in Maui; the latter on Big Island...two different islands?